# Get custom User's public folder images list in Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am developing Dropbox API application in android.
I want to make users access my public folder.
But I can't find any solution without authentication.

Is there anyway to access my public folder and list files via Dropbox API?

Comment: with authentication, you can't. Not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to list the contents of a user's Public folder

Comment: I ended up using uploadcare instead.